# Error occurred during the ProjectSummaryWebPart.OnInit. System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: 2016, filenotfoundexception, project-summary-web-part

Whenever am trying to add a ProjectSummary webpart to my page, am getting below error.

> An error occurred during the ProjectSummaryWebPart.OnInit.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file
>   http://dev/sitenm/Pages/TestofProjectSummaryWP.aspx?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design
>   does not exist.

Not able to find any solution or help on internet.

Kindly provide some pointer / how to investigate this.